# Combine multiple row in MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql

So I have 2 tables, invoices and invoiceitems. I am wanting to create a query that combines the two into one table for a report. The problem I am running into is my query is only returning the first row from tblinvoiceitems, not all that apply. See my code below. Thanks!

Here are the tables:

```
invoices
+------+----------+-------------+-------------+------------+----------+-------+---------+
|  id  |  userid  |   duedate   |  datepaid   |  subtotal  |  credit  |  tax  |  total  |
+------+----------+-------------+-------------+------------+----------+-------+---------+
| 662  | 436      | 2012-07-01  | 2012-06-05  | 1290.00    | 0.00     | 0.00  | 1290.00 |
+------+----------+-------------+-------------+------------+----------+-------+---------+
| 668  | 441      | 2012-07-01  | 2012-06-11  | 1290.00    | 0.00     | 0.00  | 1290.00 |
+------+----------+-------------+-------------+------------+----------+-------+---------+

invoiceitems
+------+-------------+----------+----------+---------+-----------------+----------+
|  id  |  invoiceid  |  userid  |   type   |  relid  |   description   |  amount  |
+------+-------------+----------+----------+---------+-----------------+----------+
| 1408 | 662         | 436      | Promo    | 436     | Setup Fee       | 295.00   |
+------+-------------+----------+----------+---------+-----------------+----------+
| 1409 | 662         | 436      |          | 0       | US Standard     | 995.00   |
+------+-------------+----------+----------+---------+-----------------+----------+
| 1425 | 668         | 441      | Promo    | 441     | Setup Fee       | 295.00   |
+------+-------------+----------+----------+---------+-----------------+----------+
| 1426 | 668         | 441      |          | 0       | US Standard     | 995.00   |
+------+-------------+----------+----------+---------+-----------------+----------+
```

The table I want:

```
newtable
+------+----------+-------------+-------------+-------------+---------+-----------+------------+
|  id  |  userid  |  invoiceid  |   duedate   |  datepaid   |  setup  |  hosting  |  subtotal  |
+------+----------+-------------+-------------+-------------+---------+-----------+------------+
| 1    | 436      | 662         | 2012-07-01  | 2012-06-05  | 295.00  | 995.00    | 1290.00    |
+------+----------+-------------+-------------+-------------+---------+-----------+------------+
| 2    | 441      | 668         | 2012-07-01  | 2012-06-11  | 295.00  | 995.00    | 1290.00    |
+------+----------+-------------+-------------+-------------+---------+-----------+------------+
```

Current query:

```
"INSERT INTO newtable SELECT
tblinvoices.id,
tblinvoices.userid,
tblinvoices.duedate,
tblinvoices.datepaid,
tblinvoices.subtotal,
tblinvoiceitems.invoiceid,
tblinvoiceitems.amount
FROM tblinvoices
INNER JOIN tblinvoiceitems ON tblinvoices.id = tblinvoiceitems.invoiceid";
```

Comment: Show your current query, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```
SELECT 
  i.id AS InvoiceID, i.userid, ii.invoiceid, i.duedate, 
  i.datepaid, i.setup, i.hosting, i.subtotal
FROM
  invoices i 
INNER JOIN 
  invoiceitems ii ON i.id = ii.id
```

Comment: This gets me a lot closer than I was! Thanks Sarfraz!

Answer (score 0):

Use combination of distinct, 2 LEFT JOINs and WHERE clauses.

```
SELECT DISTINCT <***>
LEFT JOIN invoiceitems ii0 ON ii0.id=i.invoiceid
LEFT JOIN invoiceitems ii1 ON ii1.id=i.invoiceid
WHERE ii0.description = 'Setup Fee'
  ANN ii1.description = 'US Standard'
```

Also, you'd better create separate table for description, and descriptionInvoiceItemRelation table.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Comment: I dont see `Setup Fee` and `US Standard` requirement in his question, also in his tables there is no `description` field.

Comment: @Sarfraz that's how I saw `setup` and `hosting` columns dependencies. Now I see that it's relid most likely.